# Как инициализировать динамический массив так, чтобы не было разыменования пустого указателя?

Tags: c, visual-studio, динамические-массивы

К примеру, вот код. Выскакивает предупреждение, мозолит глаза, а возможно я не ведаю об страшных опасностях, которые этот код может за собой повлечь.

```
int size = 5;
int* tmp = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * size);
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    tmp[i] = i; // Здесь выскакивает предупреждение
}
```

Comment: Каждое предупреждение и его решение легко гуглится [ссылка](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/cpp/code-quality/c6011?view=msvc-170)

Answer (score 1):

Например,

```
int size = 5;
int* tmp = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * size);
assert(tmp); 
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
```

или

```
int size = 5;
int* tmp = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * size);
if (tmp) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
```

Словом, обеспечьте проверку того, что `malloc` и в самом деле выделил вам запрошенные 20 байт памяти.